# Porbable virus in Windows 10

Tags: antivirus

I have a windows 10 machine with AVG Free antivirus.
Lately everytime I boot the machine up as soon as it gets to the desktop Chrome opens up on its own with a suspicios add to download stuff I do not need and a pop up to enable notifications from that site.

I ran several full scans and today a boot scan but I am unable to get rid of this.

What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check your browser extensions, you may have download an malicious extension. Another thing I would do is check your **Start-Up** folder in your OS. This is all I can think about. Next time don't download or install any 3d software/extension that looks suspicious, same for ads.

**The Start-Up folder in Windows located in:**

```
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: And Google for `Sysinternals Autostart` and run it. It shows anything that starts with the computer, from obvious Startup folder links to autoloaded DLL's.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like *browser hijacking* than a *virus*. There are some issues with detecting this kind of malware with an antivirus software. They might be bundled with a legitimate software or a browser extension you are willingly installing. Additionally, a browser hijacker doesn't necessarily install anything new, but alters browser settings. It's hard to detect whether these settings are wanted or not, unless the anti-malware tool is designed to prevent or find unwanted system modifications.

There are some removal hints on several sites defining browser hijacking, including:

- Kaspersky: [What Is Browser Hijacking?](https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/threats/browser-hijacking)
- Malwarebytes: [Browser hijacker](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/threats/browser-hijacker/)
- Paul Cucu, Heimdal Security:
  [Browser hijacker: Definition, Removal and Prevention Guide](https://heimdalsecurity.com/blog/browser-hijacker/)